# How to reclaim memory of single activity on destroy?

Tags: android, memory, android-activity, dalvik

How can we reclaim resource of activity on destroy??
Is is possible that we delete Activity from memory and reclaim resource immediately?
How to free Ram  resource in Android ??
I know how to kill an application using Process.killProcess(Process.myPid()) and reclaim resource but i wanted this for application having multiple activity and we delete only single activity from memory..

Comment: on orientation changes Activity recreate and memory increase Activity not release the memory even u put ur mobile for 1 hour .in my application i m using <activity android:name=".LoginOnline"
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
and override onConfigurationChanged method ..if i m using same layout for portrait and landscape mode then memory not increase even we rotate thousand times but if i m using different layout memory increase on each orientation? can we  release Activity memory manually?

Comment: Sounds like a memory leak. Check out: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Answer (score 2):

> How to reclaim memory of single activity on destroy?

So long as you are not holding onto the activity via some static reference (e.g., static data member, background thread, etc.), the activity will be eligible for garbage collection after `onDestroy()` completes. If you are concerned that perhaps you are indeed preventing your activity from being garbage collected, [use MAT to try to determine what is keeping it around](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html).

> Is is possible that we delete Activity from memory and reclaim resource immediately?

No, no more than you can "delete" anything in a garbage-collected runtime environment.

> How to free Ram resource in Android ?

Let go of the "Ram resource" when you no longer need it, and it will be garbage collected.

> I know how to kill an application using Process.killProcess(Process.myPid())

Please don't do that.

Comment: on orientation changes Activity recreate and memory increase Activity not release the memory even u put ur mobile for hours.in my application i m using <activity android:name=".LoginOnline"
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
and override onConfigurationChanged method ..if i m using same layout for portrait and landscape mode then memory not increase even we rotate thousand times but if i m using different layout memory increase on each orientation? if u change orientation 20 time in single activity application force close with out of memory error??how to resolve that?

Comment: @NitinGupta: If you are concerned that perhaps you are leaking memory, use MAT to try to determine what you are leaking. "can we release Activity memory manually?" -- as I already said in the answer, no.

Comment: Agreed. It sounds like a memory leak. Check out http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html